# How to correctly increment or decrement the day in a date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set in Javascript as data attribute to a h5 on button click the current date, next day date and previous day date.

So if today is 10 April the next day should be 11 the next 12 while the previous have to work in the inverse mode.

The problem is that in my code the days are set two by two or better if today is 10 April the next day will be 12 and next 14 but i can't get where is the problem.

Here is the javascript part

```js
function setData(data) {
  if (data == "today") {
    $("#day").attr('data-giorno', new Date());
  }
  
  if (data == "prev") {
    var ieri = new Date($("#day").attr('data-giorno'));
    ieri.setDate(ieri.getDate() - 1);
    $("#day").attr('data-giorno', ieri);
  }
  
  if (data == "next") {
    var domani = new Date($("#day").attr('data-giorno'));
    domani.setDate(domani.getDate() + 1);
    $("#day").attr('data-giorno', domani);
  }
}

$('.btn-group input[type="button"][data-calendar-nav]').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.click(function() {
    setData($this.data('calendar-nav'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row  text-center">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="pull-left">
      <h3 id="day" data-giorno="Wed Apr 10 2019 16:53:47 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale)">10 aprile 2019</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-calendar-nav="prev" value="<<" />
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm" data-calendar-nav="today" value="Oggi" />
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-calendar-nav="next" value=">>" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan actually even if i set it value in a variable the result is still the same while in debug it return the right data value https://imgur.com/NxZnm9l

Comment: The snippet doesn't appear to display the issue you describe. The `data-giorno` attribute increments/decrements by a day on each click.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i've just made a gif https://gyazo.com/ae06885c9edd97fe68ff7f38eeb67734 that show's my problem

Comment: I believe you have the problem in your working code, however the code you placed in the question doesn't have the problem, and we can only effectively solve problems with code that recreates it. Can you please edit the question to include more of your code. That being said, my first suggestion would be to remove the event handler in the `each()` loop as that's asking for trouble. Try just `$('.btn-group input[type="button"][data-calendar-nav]').click(function() { setData($(this).data('calendar-nav')); });`

Comment: My guess is you are doing the same thing again (adding/subtracting) whenever you use that attribute value in another part of your code

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan actually i don't know how but by rewriting the same code all worked, thank you for your time guys